# Finding distribution of $-\frac{1}{\theta}\log X$ where $X$ is uniform$(0,\theta)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

As a homework problem, I'm supposed to show that if $X$ is uniform$(0,\theta)$, then $-\frac{1}{\theta}\log X$ is exponential with parameter $\theta$.

Here's what I did so far:

Let $Y = -\frac{1}{\theta}\log X$. Then:

$P(Y \leq y) = P(-\frac{1}{\theta}\log X \leq y) = P(X \geq e^{-\theta y}) = \int_{e^{-\theta y}}^{\theta} \frac{1}{\theta} dx = 1 - \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\theta y}$

But if $Y$ were exponential, it should just be $1 - e^{-\theta y}$. I'm thinking there must be a mistake with the integral but I'm not sure what it could be. The probability density function over the region should be $\frac{1}{\theta}$, and $X$ is only nonzero up to $\theta$, so I thought the limits were correct. Thus I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is right, the $Y$ as defined in the post does not have exponential distribution.

The definition should have been 
$$Y=-\frac{1}{\theta}\log\left(\frac{X}{\theta}\right).$$
 Then a calculation much like yours gives that $Y$ has cdf $1-e^{-\theta y}$ on the interval $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up realizing that there was a typo from the comment you made (now deleted) and adjusted accordingly.

Comment: You are welcome. A simpler way of seeing that the distribution is (almost) never exponential is that the "bottom" value of $Y$ as defined in the post is $-(1/\theta)\log\theta$. For an exponential this ought to be $0$ but is not unless $\theta=1$.

Comment: These two RV's simply differ by a constant.

Comment: @A.S. Indeed they do, but according to the standard definition of exponential distribution, one has exponential distribution and the other has not.